# C array variable does not look like a pointer to the first array item

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, variables

All the below print the exact same memory address:

```
int nums[] = {1, 2, 3};
printf("%p\n", &nums);
printf("%p\n", nums);
printf("%p\n", &nums[0]);
```

The nums var has its own memory address, and an array is a pointer to the first item of an array. So, in the address space of nums there is a pointer (so num occupies 8 bytes). And the memory address of the first array item (last line), which is an integer, is the same as nums, which has a pointer.

So how is a pointer and number being squeezed onto the same memory block?

I expected the pointer value of nums to be different then the nums memory address. And I don’t see how it’s pointing to an integer that’s the first item in the array, I see something like int * nums = &nums, a pointer to itself (nums == &nums).

Comment: An array is not a pointer to the first element. When it's used as an L-value it's converted to a pointer to the first element.

Comment: But the parameter of the `&` operator is an R-value, not an L-value.

Comment: Hi @Barmar, I am fairly new so please demonstrate how exactly I would use the array as an L-value like you mentioned? If it is already like that, then how do I get the actual memory address of nums then?

Comment: When you use an array as a function argument, it's converted to a pointer.

Comment: Inside the function, the `&` operator will return the address of the parameter variable

Comment: Everything you're printing is the address of `nums`.

Comment: The variable IS the array.

Comment: You seem to be thinking that an array variable is similar to a pointer to a dynamically-allocated array.

Comment: @Barmar the operand of the `&` operator must be an lvalue

Comment: @PhilipKroupoderov this program output should be sufficient to convince you that "an array is a pointer" and "in the address space of nums there is a pointer" are not true

Comment: @M.M Oops I got all my R and M backwards